# Most frequently used commands during the last x months

Tags: zsh, alias

I know how to get the most used shell commands in zsh with

`history 1 | awk '{$1="";print substr($0,2)}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 20`

but is there a way to restrict myself to let's say the last two or three months?

I need this because I would like to create aliases for the commands I am **currently** using most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` in zsh have several flags to show date and time stamp. For this to work, you have to add `setopt extended_history` to your *.zshrc* file.

If you have `extended_history` enabled, `history -i` will show full time-date stamps in ISO8601 `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm' format. Dates in this format can be compared as strings. So just change your awk script and use it to select only lines after some date.

```
history -i 1 | awk '{ if ($2 >= "2020-05-01") { $1=$2=$3="";print $0; } }'  | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

Be aware that if you have `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` or `HIST_IGNORE_DUPS` options enabled, this will not work as intended.

You can also use `date` command to get older date automatically.

Comment: For some reason this only shows commands consisting of a single word, e.g. 'cd', whereas the command in my post also shows composite commands like 'cd ~/some_directory/'

Comment: Oh, that was a feature.. I edited my answer so now it should show command and all the parameters.